# Passing values in a URL string

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/    TR/    x    html1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Oncall Lookup</title>

<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

</div>
<div class="style1">
    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="TimeDateLabel" runat="server" style="text-align: center"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />


        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="schednameTextBox" runat="server" style="text-align: center"></    asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="schednameValidator" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="schednameTextBox" ErrorMessage="This is a required field">This 
    is a required field</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    Schedule Name<br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="sincedateTextBox" runat="server" style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="sincedateValidator" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="sincedateTextBox" ErrorMessage="This is a required field">This 
    is a required field</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    Since Date<br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="whosoncallButton" runat="server" Text="Who's On Call" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="clearButton" runat="server" Text="Clear" />
    <br />
    <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"      HorizontalAlign="Center"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SchedName" HeaderText="SchedName" 
                SortExpression="SchedName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityDate" HeaderText="ActivityDate" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ActivityDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="By" HeaderText="By" SortExpression="By" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Activity" HeaderText="Activity" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="Activity" />
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Firstlisting" SortExpression="Firstlisting"> 
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:HyperLink ID="Firstlisting" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Firstlisting") %>' 
                NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("\website1\Default3.aspx?firstlisting={0}", Eval("Firstlisting")) %>' /> 
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>   
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OncallStart" SortExpression="OnCallStart"> 
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:HyperLink ID="OnCallStart" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OncallStart") %>' 
         NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("\website1\Default2.aspx?date={0}&schedname={1}", Eval("OncallStart"), Eval("Schedname")) %>' /> 
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>   
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OnCallEnd" HeaderText="OnCallEnd" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="OnCallEnd" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MDRConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="sp_getoncallresults2" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="sincedateTextBox" DbType="Datetime" 
                Name="sincedate" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="schednameTextBox" Name="schedname" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="nodataLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
</form>
```

and when I try to pass certain variables to my next page, they're not being passed. I was told that I'm not accounting for ampersands and blacks in my URL string. What is the best way to do that?

Thank you

Doug

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at `css` to manage the layout of your page and avoid all the `<br />` tags and `&nbsp;` which you have in your markup

Answer (score 0):

You need to url endode the query parameter:

```
<asp:HyperLink 
    ID="Firstlisting" 
    runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("Firstlisting") %>' 
    NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/website1/Default3.aspx?firstlisting={0}", Server.UrlEncode((string)Eval("Firstlisting"))) %>' 
/>
```

Comment: Darin,What needs to go where you have (string?)

Comment: @Doug Ancil, a `string` :-) The `Server.UrlEncode` method requires a string parameter. If your `Firstlisting` property that you are evaling is not a string you might need to call a `.ToString` before.

Comment: Darin, the string is being passed from the page. It's a link from one page to the next. This is new to me so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Darin, thanks ... I didn't know how to write that code but it works now. Thank you

Comment: @Doug Ancil, if this post helped you solve the issue you were having you might consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.